# R, ggplot2: reverse alphabetical order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use ggplot2 to create a graph using

```
dat <- data.frame(xx=c("IND","AUS","USA"), yy=c(1,5,2))
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=reorder(xx,xx), y=yy))
```

and this nicely sorts my x-axis alphabetically. However, I want to sort the string variable `xx` in reverse alphabetical order but cannot seem to get it. While `reorder(yy,-yy)` can sort my numeric variable, `reorder(xx,-xx)` does not work.

Comment: show your work, you are more likely to get help if we can modify your code rather than writing an example by ourselves.

Comment: Yes a reproducible example is actually a requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=forcats::fct_rev(reorder(xx,xx)), y=yy))
```

Comment: Works! But it appears odd that it requires an additional package. Is there really no solution in base R to reverse-order factors?

Comment: You can do it in base R. Just do it before you plot: `dat$xx <- factor(dat$xx, levels = c(sort(unique(dat$xx), decreasing = TRUE)))`